# How do I fix "ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-sysv.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored"?

Tags: bash, llvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, manpage

When I watch the documentation for clang-formatter, on the top of the Man page, I see the following.

```
CLANG-FORMAT(1)                                             User Commands                                            CLANG-FORMAT(1)

NAME
       clang-format - manual page for clang-format 4.0

DESCRIPTION
       ERROR:  ld.so:  object  'libfakeroot-sysv.so'  from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
       OVERVIEW: A tool to format C/C++/Java/JavaScript/Objective-C/Protobuf code.
```

How do I fix the error I see before the *Overview* part?

> ERROR:  ld.so:  object  'libfakeroot-sysv.so'  from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

If that makes a difference, I am seeing it when I run `man clang-formatter` on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

The output of /usr/bin/env doesn't show any *LD_PRELOAD* variable, so I am not sure why the command would try to load the *libfakeroot-sysv.so* dynamic library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 'ERROR' line is likely actually written in the manpage itself and is not an issue with your system.

You can verify this by examining the relevant manpage's file under /usr/share/man.

For example, I found this 'ERROR' line under Ubuntu 17.04's modularize-4.0 manpage. To verify that it was actually written there, I ran:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/modularize-4.0.1.gz | less
```